# django bulk insert using value from parent table instead of ID

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-models

I have 2 models -- `AssetType` and `Asset` (both have IDs and Asset has a foreign key point to AssetType)

I want to bulk insert rows in the Asset table using Asset Type NAME, instead of ID.

I tried to do df.to_sql() but it can't work because my df contains "asset type name" instead of asset type id. Is there a way to convert it easily?

#### Expected Output

The asset type table looks like this:

```
id | name | description
1  | at1  | desc1
```

The Asset table should look like this

```
asset_name | display_name | asset_type_id
n1         | d1           | 1
```

The dataframe I want to insert in the Asset table looks like this (**Input**): -- notice im inserting asset_type_name and it should get converted into asset_type_id

```
asset_name | display_name | asset_type_name
n1         | d1           | at1
```

So, I am passing in `at1` in my dataframe but want to insert it as "id=1" for asset type. Is this possible in django?

My models are:

```
class AssetType(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Asset(models.Model):
    asset_type = models.ForeignKey(AssetType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    asset_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

My serializer looks like this:

```
class AssetTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AssetType
        fields = "__all__"


class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    asset_type_name = serializers.CharField(source='asset_type.name')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = ("id", "asset_type_name", "asset_name", "display_name")
```

My View looks something like this:

```
class AssetViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing accounts.
    """
    queryset = Asset.objects.select_related()
    serializer_class = AssetSerializer

    @action(methods=['POST'], detail=False)
    def bulk_create(self, request):

        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(request.data['data']))
        df.to_sql(Asset._meta.db_table, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=500)
```

Django version - 3.2
Database - SQL server

Comment: Asset_type_name is unique. In my AssetType model it says `unique=True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach I can think of is to use django's [`in_bulk`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk), to populate a dictionary that uses the asset type name as key and the asset type instance as value:

```py
# This will create {'asset_type_name': asset_type_instance} mapping
asset_types = AssetType.objects.in_bulk(field_name='name')
```

Then pass it to the serializer as context:

```py
serializer = AssetSerializer(
    data=request.data['data'], many=True, 
    context={'asset_types_map': asset_types},
)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
serializer.save()
```

And then use the map on a custom create, using the asset type name in the data to get the asset type instance like this:

```
class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    asset_type_name = serializers.CharField(source='asset_type.name')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = ("id", "asset_type_name", "asset_name", "display_name") 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        asset_type_name = validated_data.pop('asset_type_name')
        validated_data['asset_type'] = self.context['asset_types_map'].get(asset_type_name)
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Haven't tested this so might fail here and there, but the gist is here.

Comment: I just updated the question with my view. I'm using `.to_sql()`. I dont think it will enter the "create" function in serializer? Maybe I can use the dict you created to replace the name with id in my `bulk_create()` function

Comment: Oh ok I thought you are using the serializers to save the objects as well. Yeah I think that should be fine as well. But looking at your update, you can just use `request.data` in the serializer? But up to you

Comment: I have no opinions on this -- fairly new to django. Using `request.data` in serializer is more efficient is it? Could you help me how I could do that?

Comment: I don't know much about pandas, but you can profile the speed of both approach and compare. Updated by answer to show how you can use the serializer to save to the db.

Answer (score 0):

---

Answering my own question for anyone in the future having the same problem.

Heavily inspired by @bdbd's answer but didn't need the dictionary or the context part.

Here is the code which worked:

The viewset was fairly simple. Accept request data and pass to serializer

```
class AssetViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Asset.objects.select_related()
    serializer_class = AssetSerializer

    @action(methods=['POST'], detail=False)
    def bulk_create(self, request):
        serializer = AssetSerializer(
            data=request.data['data'], many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

In the serializer, query the asset type object from the name and send it as a part of creating asset object.

```
class AssetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    asset_type_name = serializers.CharField(source='asset_type.name')
    
    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = ("id", "asset_type_name", "asset_name", "display_name")    

    def create(self, validated_data):
        asset_type = validated_data.pop('asset_type')
        asset_type = AssetType.objects.get(**asset_type)
        return Asset.objects.create(**validated_data, asset_type=asset_type)
```

#### Update

Based on the comment below by @bdbd,
this method works but `in_bulk` saves the number of queries to the db so that is more preferable to use.
Leaving this answer here just in case.

Comment: While this will work, note that it will hit the database for every line in `request.data['data']` just to get the `AssetType`. The reason I used `in_bulk` in my answer is to avoid this and improve performance. But if this is a one-off thing, then this should do.

Comment: Okay thanks for the tip -- I changed my method to use `in_bulk` only!